# How to resize a video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, osmf

I'm building a player with two switchable sizes, changed by the user, but I'm not having results on that.

That's my setupPlayer function, which works fine:

```
function setupPlayer():void
{

            layout.width  = _playerWidth;
            layout.height = _playerHeight;
            layout.layoutMode = LayoutMode.HORIZONTAL
            layout.horizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.CENTER;
            layout.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.TOP;
            layout.scaleMode = ScaleMode.LETTERBOX;

            videoElement.addMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE, layout);
            videoElement.smoothing = true;

            mediaPlayer.loop = false;
            mediaPlayer.autoPlay = _autoPlay;             
            mediaContainer.addMediaElement(videoElement);
            videoCanvas.addChild(mediaContainer);       

               .... // more code //
}
```

Then, I feed the player and it starts to play normally, it's when I try to resize it. (I did read somewhere that I needed to change the LayoutMetadata), but have no effect:

```
public function resize(width:Number, height:Number):void
{
            // none of this worked
            //mediaContainer.width = 1200;
            //mediaContainer.height = 2000;
            //mediaContainer.layout(1200, 2000, true);


            // neither this
            var layout:LayoutMetadata = new LayoutMetadata();
            layout.width  = 1500;
            layout.height = 1500;
            layout.layoutMode = LayoutMode.HORIZONTAL
            layout.horizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.CENTER;
            layout.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.TOP;
            layout.scaleMode = ScaleMode.STRETCH;

            videoElement.removeMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE)
            videoElement.addMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE, layout);
}
```

Someone can point where my error is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, I had to change mediaContainer dimensions **and** define a new layoutMetadata for my current videoElement:

```
public function resize(width:Number, height:Number):void
{
            mediaContainer.width  = width;
            mediaContainer.height = height;

            var layout:LayoutMetadata = new LayoutMetadata();
            layout.width  = width;
            layout.height = height;
            layout.layoutMode = LayoutMode.HORIZONTAL;
            layout.horizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.CENTER;
            layout.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.TOP;
            layout.scaleMode = ScaleMode.STRETCH;

            videoElement.removeMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE);
            videoElement.addMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE, layout);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of setting width and height properties of the VideoElement, set the MediaContainer's width and height to _playerWidth and _playerHeight respectively. Try the code below and see if it solves you problem

```
function setupPlayer():void
{

            mediaContainer.width = _playerWidth;
            mediaContainer.height = _playerHeight;

            layout.layoutMetadata.percentWidth = 100;
            layout.layoutMetadata.percentHeight = 100;
            layout.scaleMode = ScaleMode.LETTERBOX;

            videoElement.addMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE, layout);
            videoElement.smoothing = true;

            mediaPlayer.loop = false;
            mediaPlayer.autoPlay = _autoPlay;             
            mediaContainer.addMediaElement(videoElement);
            videoCanvas.addChild(mediaContainer);       

               .... // more code //
}

public function resize(width:Number, height:Number):void
{
            // none of this worked
            mediaContainer.width = 1200;
            mediaContainer.height = 2000;
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do that correctly, I need to change mediaContainer **and** set a new layouMetadata.